# Scaling encodedImage

Tags: codenameone

How can we scale encodedImage with respect to width and the height just scale with proportion to width? We can scaleWidth of image but there is no scaledEncodedWidth. Is there a way to scale width of encoded image and height scale with respect to the width?

code:

```
homePlaceholder = (EncodedImage) r.getImage("placeholder.png");
homePlaceholder = homePlaceholder.scaledEncoded(screenWidth / 3, screenWidth / 3);
//the following doesnt work as well
homePlaceholder = homePlaceholder.scaledEncoded(screenWidth / 3, -1);
```

Comment: This is indeed an omission in EncodedImage I've added an improvement to support the -1 notation for the next update of the libs: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/EncodedImage.html#scaledEncoded-int-int-

Answer (score 1):

I hope replacing EncodedImage with Image will solve your problem as shown in following code

```
Image homePlaceholder =(Image) r.getImage("placeholder.png");
homePlaceholder = homePlaceholder.scaledWidth(screenWidth / 3);

EncodedImage encodedHomePlaceholder =   EncodedImage.createFromImage(homePlaceholder , true)
```